# Viewbag properties inside action link helper

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I was trying to include and viewbag object inside an actionlink helper.

```
@Html.ActionLink( "Date" + ViewBag.icon , "Index", new{ sortBy=ViewBag.DateSort})
```

Logic for my Viewbag.

```
ViewBag.icon = (ViewBag.DateSort ==  "Date desc") ? "▼" :"▲";
```

I am implement sort here.

Comment: Is there an actual question here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add DateSort to your ViewBag in your Controller, and do this in your View:

```
@{
  var dateHeader = "Date " + (ViewBag.DateSort ==  "Date desc" ? "▼" : "▲");
}

@Html.ActionLink(dateHeader, "Index", new { sortBy = ViewBag.DateSort })
```